# OpenID development and debugging tools

Tags: openid

Any pointers to development, primarily debugging tools, for OpenID?  In particular, I'm looking for a tool to record and view the OpenID traffic through the User-Agent during an indirect communication authentication session.  An OpenID provider and relying party that offered debugging info about authentication attempts would be nice, too.

Yes, I've asked Mr. Google about this, and haven't hit the right keywords or I wouldn't be asking here.  I can build this myself, but if someone else has already done the work...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DotNetOpenAuth library does both RP and OP and has very verbose logging for diagnostic purposes, which can be tuned to whatever logs you're interested in.  You can use it to test against your OpenID site, regardless of what its platform is.

You can check out a sample of the logs by logging into the [demo RP](http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/) and then visiting the [log page](http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/tracepage.aspx) that it accumulated from your login.

Then there's the equivalent [demo OP](http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/OpenIdProviderWebForms/) and the associated [log page](http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/OpenIdProviderWebForms/TracePage.aspx).

If you like what you see, you can either just use these sites yourself to test your OpenID site against, or you can [download DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) and use it locally and further customize the logs.

Comment: All links dead.  Host not found

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions on where you might find information other than google: there are a few links on [dmoz](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Security/Authentication/Single_Sign-On/OpenID/), and there are several OpenID related project on [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/search?q=openid&submit=Search) and [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=openid). While you might not find what you ask for there, perhaps you could directly ask one or some of the authors of the various openid servers or post on corresponding mailing lists. I would assume that some of those have done their share of debugging and would have some tips to provide.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer is nice, but outdated - his links are 404
However his links were great starting point.

Now links are http://test-id.net/OP/AXFetch.aspx and the rest on that site :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [TamperData](http://tamperdata.mozdev.org/) extension for FireFox is what I used to look at communication through the user-agent.  The script "openid-parse" in python-openid/contrib/ will take data copied out of a TamperData logs and parse it out into OpenID fields for you.